# error MongoDB driver while using crontab

Tags: php, mongodb, cron

I lauch a script with crontab every 2min. This script is using a php file using MongoDB. When I lauch the file via the browser, everything works perfect. But when its lauched by cron, it sends this error :

***Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in myfile.php on line 19***

Can you please help me understand ? Mongo Driver is installed correctly since the scrip works well via my browser..

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "by cron" does that mean you are running the CLI SAPI rather than the web SAPI? What OS is this running on? Where did you source the PHP implementation? What version of PHP?

Comment: im running the script via crontab (OSX terminal). My PHP version is 7.0.15

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to enable mongodb for php cli separately.
To check if it is already enabled, in your command line, try : `php -m | grep -i mongo`

If no results is output, enable it on `cli/php.ini` file. ex: In latest ubuntu versions it is located at `/etc/php/[Your_PHP_Version]/cli/php.ini`

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Sierra

Answer (score 0):

my php.ini has the mongodb extension as well : extension=mongodb.so
I'm using Mamp